# What is use of arguments in add_filter function in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Actually i little bit confused about this function mentioned below.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_loginout_link', 10, 2 );
```

What is role of 10,2 in this function.

Answer (score 1):

(your "10") $priority : (int) (Optional) Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.

```
Default value: 10
```

(your "2") $accepted_args (int) (Optional) The number of arguments the function accepts.

```
Default value: 1
```

[Wordpress doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)

Answer (score 0):

WordPress offers filter hooks to allow plugins to modify various types of internal data at runtime.
**Syntax**

```
add_filter ( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority , $accepted_args);
```

**$tag**

```
(string) (Required) The name of the filter to hook the $function_to_add callback to.
```

**$function_to_add**

```
(callable) (Required) The callback to be run when the filter is applied.
```

**$priority**

```
(int) (Optional) Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.

Default value: 10
```

**$accepted_args**

```
(int) (Optional) The number of arguments the function accepts.

Default value: 1
```